# Finding substrings that contain each other in two different lists in Pytyhon

Tags: python, string, list, substring

Really basic question, but I couldn't find the way to properly achieve this.

I have two lists:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```

and

```
usernames = ['example1', 'zzzzz23', 'eeeee43', 'llllll5', 'pppapp1', 'wwsd0']
```

I want, to extract from `usernames` all elements that don't have `vowels` in them.

I tried:

```
usernames_without_vowels = []
for username in usernames:
  if str(vowels) not in username:
    usernames_without_vowels.append(username)
  else: pass
print(usernames_without_vowels)
```

**OUTPUT 1:**

`>> ['example1', 'zzzzz23', 'eeeee43', 'llllll5', 'pppapp1', 'wwsd0']`

As you can see, it printed the whole `usernames` list, as it seems to not look for substrings too.

I then tried zipping both lists as it follows:

```
usernames_without_vowels = []
for username,vowel in zip(usernames,vowels):
  if str(vowels) not in str(username):
    usernames_without_vowels.append(username)
  else: pass
print(usernames_without_vowels)
```

but, then again:
**OUTPUT 2:**

`>> ['example1', 'zzzzz23', 'eeeee43', 'llllll5', 'pppapp1']`

it printed the whole `usernames` list EXCEPT the last value: `wwsd0`.

Also tried:

```
usernames_without_vowels = [username for username in usernames if str(vowels) not in username]
print(usernames_without_vowels)
```

and **OUTPUT 3:**
`>> ['example1', 'zzzzz23', 'eeeee43', 'llllll5', 'pppapp1', 'wwsd0']`

I want to get all usernames in which EACH STRING of `vowels` is NOT present, but can't find a way.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
>> ['zzzzz23', 'llllll5', 'wwsd0']
```

**SOLUTION**

Following @Helios solution, it was accomplished by:

```
username_without_vowels = [u for u in usernames if not any([v in u for v in vowels])]
```

Simple, and (very) effective.

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Might help to add your expected output too!

Comment: @Helios Done! Updated the question and added your solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[u for u in usernames if not any(v in u for v in vowels)]`

EDIT:

Updated to include @cglacet comment

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! Can't believe I spent over an hour and couldn't solve it. You just saved my day. Thank you!

Comment: List comp is almost always the way, its performant (compared to a loop) and ends up with compact readable code

Comment: Note that you can write `any(v in u for v in vowels)` directly, [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) works on iterables (which generators are)

Comment: Thanks, and would mean that it would exit early if it already found a True, hence saving some work instead of constructing the full list

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to skin this cat, one way is to use `set intersection` and filter out all results that have results of such an intersection.

```
vowels = set(vowels)

[user for user in usernames if len(vowels.intersection(user)) == 0]

# OR

[user for user in usernames if not vowels.intersection(user)]
```

Both yield

```
> ['zzzzz23', 'llllll5', 'wwsd0']
```

Comment: Thank you! It is useful you added two ways to accomplish it!